# How to create web server to provide data to Android application

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, webserver

I'm not new to programming, but I have never created any server applications. I wish to a create server that provides data to an Android application, for example using a JSON string by POST/GET http requests that saves some data. I want to use Java EE,  but I am unsure whether that is possible. I found tutorials that provide web browser pages, but I don't need this. Can somebody advise me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are looking for simple *JSON* data representation, I would recommend going through a RESTful backend service and when it says REST in a Java Enterprise Edition, it says *JAX-RS* (RESTful Java specification) and its base implementation reference: [*Jersey*](https://jersey.java.net/).

It should not be the perfect place to detail how to implement a simple JSON backed service using *Jersey*, but going through the site references you should gain the basic knowledge on how to go for your first simple REST service.